# How to start worker in apache storm

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, apache-storm

During topology submit, my supervisor automatically got shutdown and also worker not started yet. In my storm ui, there was no data available under supervisor summary.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already submit the topology successfully, you can just restart your supervisor then the worker assigned to that supervisor will be relaunched by the supervisor

Comment: i am not able to submit my topology on VM and able to get all the necessary info but when i am submitting my topology locally i can submit but the supervisor got shutdown and again i am submitting again shutdown after 1 or 2 minutes. Please help me